# Need help changing macro from drawing information from mulitple workbooks into rows instead of columns

Tags: vba, excel

Would really appreciate help from anyone in changing the below code from drawing information from different spreadsheets into Rows instead of Columns.

Currently it will draw the information into B1:E3 for sheet 1 then F1:I3 for sheet 2 etc.

I need it to draw the information into rows instead so for sheet 1 B1:F3 then sheet 2 B4:F6

```
Sub Get_Columns()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFil As String
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim twb As Workbook

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xl*")

Do While sFil <> "" And sFil <> twb.Name
    Set owb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFil)
    owb.Sheets("Foot").Range("C15:F17").Copy twb.Sheets("Ball").Cells(, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    owb.Close False
    sFil = Dir
Loop

    With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using `(, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)` in your paste destination, `(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much for helping me out, when I input your code it says that End(x1Up) is empty and I get an error, any ideas?

Comment: Just checking - did you type `xlUp` or `x1Up` - the letter "l" or the number "1"?

Comment: Just tried the letter l after I typed that Ben, sorry! major fail on my end, thank you!!